# Google Drive insert file "404 Not Found: ID" but ID is NOT the ID I sent in request

Tags: google-drive-api

Title basically says it all.

From research, [and this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084643/getting-a-404-when-trying-to-upload-a-file-to-the-google-drive-api-suspecting-a), this seems to be the error for when the Parent Folder ID is wrong / does not exist in an insert request. But, the ID in the error is not the parent folder ID I sent in the request.

Ocassionally when in the process of inserting thousands of files sequentially, I'll get an error like so:

```
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "file",
    "locationType" : "other",
    "message" : "File not found: 0B0F9AQJRAt1gUkJSWHJIRGt1cVU",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "File not found: 0B0F9AQJRAt1gUkJSWHJIRGt1cVU"
}
```

However, the ID shown at "File not found: ..." is NOT an ID I provided. I'm not sure of where that's coming from.

My few thoughts for possible explanations:

1. ID is a specific folder higher up in the hierarchy that did not load / resolve correctly
2. An old deleted folder which hasn't completely gone away and was still in the cache / causing issues

Has any one experienced this, any ideas?

Comment: Hey, can you share your code, or explain what you are trying to do

Comment: 2 is more likely than 1. Folders don't really form a hierarchy, they're more like  tags/labels.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this problem. Passing in a dummy ID I always get the same ID back in the error. Do you have a way to consistently trigger this behavior?